# Curly brackets in italics

Tags: brackets, italic

How do I italicise curly brackets { }?

I try:

```
{\it Method \rightarrow \{\ \!"EquationSimplification" \rightarrow "Solve"\}}
```

but it does not work. The brackets are not in the .pdf output...

Comment: Consider reading [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Comment: Welcome! Is this supposed to be in maths mode or text? A small, complete, compilable document would make it easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: the only braces defined in the computer modern fonts are upright.  if you really need sloped braces, you'll have to find another font (and latex support for it).  however, it's a typographic convention of long standing that in expressions like this, punctuation and delimiters are upright.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Using the T1 encoding gets you CM italic curly brackets although they need to be in text mode, of course.

Comment: @crf, it can be in text mode. Please show me how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, despite barbara's comment, you really want italic curly brackets, you might want one of these solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Text mode with arrows in maths mode:

{\itshape
  Method $\rightarrow$ \{\ ``EquationSimplification'' $\rightarrow$ ``Solve'' \}
}

Maths mode:

\[
  Method \rightarrow \text{\itshape \{}\ \!``EquationSimplification" \rightarrow ``Solve" \text{\itshape \}}
\]

\end{document}
```

I'm not clear if you really want `Method` etc. to be in maths mode. If not, you can use `\text{}` to use text while in maths mode for these as well.

[image: italic curly brackets]